# Blocking incoming traffic for interface

Tags: networking, debian, iptables, interface

I have created an interface eth0:2 and I want to make curl requests from that interface only so I want to block all ports and incoming traffic on that interface.

This iptables rule used to work, but for some reason it doesn't anymore:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0:2 -j DROP
```

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: you need to use the INPUT CHAIN for incoming traffic, http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/IPTables

Comment: If you block all incomming traffic, by definition you aren't allowing any of the stuff you are retrieving in either... make *sure* you understand what you are doing here first.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that incoming traffic is directly addressed to the machine itself, so it will hit the `INPUT` chain.

You should use the `INPUT` chain instead :

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0:2 -j DROP
```

`FORWARD` chain is hit when traffic is routed from one interface to another.